# dimensionality error with Keras convolutional layers

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, dimensions, keras-layer

The dimensions of following variables of data are as follows:

print(x_train.shape) is (1750, 784)

print(y_train.shape) is (1750, 10)

print(x_test.shape) is (749, 784)

print(y_test.shape) is (749, 10)

orig_dims is 784

inner_dims is 10

The code is below. The error I get at line 'validation_data=(x_test, [y_test,x_test]))' is InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1750,784] vs. [1750,28,28,1]
     [[Node: loss_18/dense_400_loss/logistic_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@train...ad/Reshape"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss_18/dense_400_loss/Log, _arg_dense_400_target_0_2)]] .

```
x_test = x_test.reshape(749,28,28,1)
x_train = x_train.reshape(1750,28,28,1)

#Create first input and dense layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(28,28,1))   
x = Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides = (1,1),name='layer_conv1',padding='same', 
input_shape=(28, 28, 1))(input_layer)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='maxPool1')(x)
x1 = Flatten()(x)
flatLayer1 = Dense(64,activation = 'relu',name='fc0')(x1)

encoded_layer = Dense(inner_dims, activation=activation_f)(flatLayer1)

#Create layers - 1 dense layer
for i in xrange(layers-1):
  encoded_layer = Dense(inner_dims, activation=activation_f)(encoded_layer)

#Initialize shared hidden state layer
hidden_state = Dense(orig_dims,activation=activation_f,name='h')

#Create latent layer to output
encoded = hidden_state(encoded_layer)

#Create latent layer for decoder
encoded_output = hidden_state(encoded_layer)

#Create decoder
decoded = Dense(inner_dims, activation=activation_f)(encoded_output)
for i in xrange(layers-1):
    decoded = Dense(inner_dims, activation=activation_f)(decoded)

output_layer = Dense(orig_dims, activation=activation_f)(decoded)
###output_layer = Dense(10, activation=activation_f)(decoded)

encoder = Model(input_layer, encoded)
encoder_2 = Model(input_layer,encoded_layer)

#Wrappers for keras
def custom_loss1(y_true,y_pred):
    bcro = losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true,encoded)
    return bcro


def custom_loss2(y_true,y_pred):
    recon_loss = losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return recon_loss

    autoencoder = Model(input_layer, outputs=[encoded,output_layer])
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=[custom_loss1, custom_loss2],loss_weights=[0.1, 1.])
    autoencoder.fit(x_train, [y_train,x_train],
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(x_test, [y_test,x_test]))
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: The problem is you flatten the convolution's output, in the encoder part of your model, but in decoder part, you forgot to reverse it back to recreate the original input. You can remove flatten layer both in encoder and decoder part. Take a look at [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) for more in-depth tutorial.

Comment: That still gives error. There is only 1 flatten in encoder. none in decoder. If flatten is removed, then next line in encoded_layer = Dense(inner_dims, activation=activation_f)(flatLayer1) will also fail due to inner_dims. Please check carefully and recommend.

Comment: if I change x_test to y_test in validation data-and change dimensions in output_layer to no. of calls of trainY as output_layer = Dense(10, activation=activation_f)(decoded) , then it works. In the case its left as testX, then error remains. So, output_layer dimension format has to be changed correspondingly I believe, in a different format than the input format of dimension used for CNN layers? If so how? Transposed dimension or?

Comment: @pMan Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We should be able to just copy your code and reproduce the error you get. There are some variables in your code which their values are not known to us and this makes debugging very hard for us.